# DDR4 Combining RAM kits

Tags: memory

With DDR3 I used to buy RAM "kits" one at a time to build my system up over time as and when I could afford it. I would make sure to buy the exact same "kit" from the same provider to avoid issues. E.g. buying 4 lots of 1 x 8 GB sticks or 2 lots of (2 x 8GB) etc.

I was told that I cannot do this with DDR4 and that one has to buy all 4 sticks in a single kit at once. Is this true?

Comment: No, it applies exactly the same to DDR4 as it does DDR3.

Comment: Just to clarify, that "No" is for "No, that is not true" and not "No, you cannot mix Dimm packs"

Comment: No it's not true.

Comment: It is entirely dependent on your north bridge chipset and what it will support. Google that part and supported memory, if you are on a non-branded box.

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed a local computer stores web site and found that the dimms come in either 2 or 4 packs.

For example

http://www.canadacomputers.com/product_info.php?cPath=24_311_1326&item_id=083959